# Entity Framework migration for class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create an Entity Framework migration for a class library.

Project and Library:

[image]

In my ASP.NET MVC project I created the service to access app setting

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    // ConnectionString
    services.AddDbContext<PortfolioDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("myPorfolioDb"));
        });
    }
```

App Settings

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "myPorfolioDb": "Data Source=DESKTOP-7QDCA67\\MAGSQL;Initial Catalog=MyPortfolioDB;Integrated Security=true;"
}
```

Console Gestion de Package
[Console + Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrdlJ.png)

Comment: In your `dotnet ef migrations` command, you're trying to add the initial migration to `Web.csproj`. 

You should add it to `Portfolio.Infrastructure.csproj` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run migrations command inside `Infrastructure` directory, you need to specify [startup project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#target-project-and-startup-project) because `DbContextOptions` should be injected to `DbContext` class.

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../Web/ migrations add Initial
```

or simply run migration command in `Web` project and specify the project you want to store migration.

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --project YourAssemblyName
```

In this case put assembly name of `Portfolio.Infrastructure`.

For more information read [Using a Separate Migrations Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)
.